# Joomla 3.4 custom fields names strange behavior in JForm

Tags: joomla-3.4, jform, custom-field

I'm working for FE component with form to make ability to user set some values to filter data from DB (ex: select, text). After user make submit these fields need to show values user have selected before submit.

I have created custom fields and form XML files. I realized that custom fields in same JForm that extends JFormField remains with same name that is set in myfield.php but custom fields that extends JFormFieldList become with jform array part (ex. jform[myfield]) and so they appear in the POST as part of jfrom array.

It there some workaround to make same naming (with or w/o jform) for all custom fields (JFormField, JFormFieldList, ...) and read them all using JInput as single fields or as part of array?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can go dum and override your custom_field getInput() function so your field name will be without jfrom part, but this is not good.
What you need is just make sure you use $this->value inside your custom_field.php as it cares value that user had sent.

if it is not - it must be something wrong with populateState() and getForm() inside your model.php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should have a look on [DPFields](https://joomla.digital-peak.com/products/dpfields) which can easily be integrated into your component. It does all the work for you.